# Is there a workaround for FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY, when using only a BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I want to be alerted, if a headset is plugged in. But the Intent "ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG" is used with the Flag "FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY". 
So I have to run a service or a activity all the time to get the intent? I just want to run a Broadcastreceiver and NO service or activity at all. Is there a workaround for this? Is this even possible? Or can I start a service once, registering and then stopping it?

P.S.: I know when the headset is plugged off with the becoming noisy intent.

Thank you for you answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Dianne Hackborn says](http://groups.google.com/group/android-platform/browse_thread/thread/81023e44dd5f383c)

> It's only given to those who call registerReceiver, and not sent to
>   receivers declared in manifests.

So you have to have something running that calls `registerReceiver`. It that stops running and you don't unregister the receiver you get an error.

Answer (score 0):

There are components that should be registered when the application is installed (<3.0), or at least when the application has **moved from stopped state** to started (3.0 & ICS), such as a `ContentProvider`.

The provider apparently doesn't have an "end" to it's life cycle that you have to worry (a lot) about.

Simply put, adding a `<provider>` to your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<provider android:name=".ReceiverProvider"
    android:authorities="some.provider.authority.goes.here"
    android:exported="true" />
```

And, for the `ReceiverProvider`:

```
public class ReceiverProvider extends ContentProvider {
    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                System.out.println("Headset plug: " + intent);
            }
        };
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
        getContext().registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs,
            String sortOrder) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Worth trying perhaps.

Comment: here you have the case of "not sent to receivers declared in manifests"

Comment: That's grossly **incorrect**. The receiver is not declared in a manifest, it's part of a <provider>:s onCreate - which is triggered when an application goes from stopped to started state (or immediately, if sdk_version <= 10).

Comment: oops, true. But afaik a ContentProvider does not get started until someone requests content from you. I guess you could catch `Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` and then call `context.getContentResolver().acquireContentProviderClient(Uri.parse("content://your.authority"))` to have that happen.

Comment: ContentProviders are started on the application main thread when the application is started. You do not need to request anything from it.

Comment: Yes, but I guess OP does not want users to have to start the app manually each time